# How to see the compiler-generated code for C++ coroutine code

Tags: c++, c++-coroutine

Recently I've learned materials about C++ coroutine TS and known that compiler such as clang would generate code for `co_await <expr>`. And I'm very curious to check the generated code especially the coroutine frame created on heap with some tool such as gdb, so that I'll be more impressive with this mechanism.

I've tried gdb, but no results I expects.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, why not just use the compiler switch to output the generated assembly and you can examine it.
For example:
`clang++ -S foo.cpp`
or
`g++ -S foo.cpp`
will give you `foo.s` with the asm output that will show exactly what the CPU is going to see.
If you prefer Intel syntax over AT&T, add "-masm=intel" to the command line.